# Retry to send mail if not sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send emails through my node app. Sometimes Email does not work and throws an error until I try twice or thrice. I want my program to try again and again until the mail is successfully sent.

Here's my code:

```
const mailOptions = {
    from: from,
    to: client.email,
    subject: 'Your Photos are ready',
    html: mailTemplate
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
              message: "Mail not sent",
              error
        });
    } else {
        res.status(200).json({message: "Mail Sent", response: info.response});
    }
});
```

How can I use the same function inside my `if` block?

Answer (score 3):

Wrap `sendMail` in a function that returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
const promiseWrapper = mailOptions => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        reject(error);
        return;
    }
    resolve(info);
});
```

then in your route make the handler an [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and loop how many time that you want, then check if `info` exists if it does send 200 if not send 500

```
app.post('/sendmail', async (req, res) => {
  let info;
  let error;

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    try {
      info = await promiseWrapper(mailOptions);
      break;
    } catch (e) {
      error = e;
    }
  }

  info 
    ? res.status(200).json({ message: "Mail Sent", response: info.response })
    : res.status(500).json({ message: "Mail not send", error }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first separate the retry logic in a different file, so you can use it in various places.
Newer versions of nodemailer support promises for transporter.sendMail

```js
// retry.js
// retries a function, called asynchronously, n amount of times
export async function retry(fn, n) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    try {
      return await fn()
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}
```

And pass the transporter function to the retry logic, with the amount of times you want to retry (in this example: 3)

```js
import {retry} from '../utils/retry'

// ...

app.post('/sendmail', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    retry(
      () =>
        transporter.sendMail({
          // your configuration
          from: from,
          to: client.email,
          subject: 'Your Photos are ready',
          html: mailTemplate
        }),
      3 // max retries
    )
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    // failed max retry times
    res.sendStatus(500)
  }

  res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const mailOptions = {
    from: from,
    to: client.email,
    subject: 'Your Photos are ready',
    html: mailTemplate
};

var i;
for(i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).json({
                  message: "Mail not sent",
                  error
            });
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i = 2;
            res.status(200).json({message: "Mail Sent", response: info.response});
        }
    });
}
```

Try the code above will run the function again and again if the error occur and it will exit the loop if no error occur.

Comment: For will not wait for the Asynchronous function to complete.

Comment: I did not know you are using Asynchronous function

Answer (score -1):

Wrap it into a function and call in this way:

```js
const mailOptions = {
    from: from,
    to: client.email,
    subject: 'Your Photos are ready',
    html: mailTemplate
};

function sendMail(mailOptions) {
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
            return sendMail(mailOptions)
        } else {
            return res.status(200).json({message: "Mail Sent", response: info.response});
        }
    });
}

return sendMail(mailOptions);
```