# How to fix Nodemailer problem "Error: Server terminates connection. response=421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection."

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I am trying to send emails from a Node.js/express server. I have an email on my custom domain which is sending these out. Emails would be sent out very rarely, but occasionally maybe 20 times in an hour. However it is always individually, and never in batches.

Around 50-75% of the time I try to send an email, I get this error, even within the first 2 or 3 emails:

```
Error: Server terminates connection. response=421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection.
```

My research shows its an issue with mass emailing to prevent DDoS attacks. The numbers people mention are 50+ emails within a second, however this is not my use case.

Here is how I am currently sending the mail

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp-relay.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: 'user',
        pass: 'pass'
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'source',
    to: target_email,
    subject: "suibject",
    html: "text"
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return ('Error while sending email' + err)
    }
    else {
        console.log("Email sent");
        return ('Email sent')
    }
});
```

I have tried switching ports around, but I'm at a loss for what next to try. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: For anyone coming later, there was no solution anywhere. Best I could do is retry on fail by doing [Retry to send mail if not sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920250/retry-to-send-mail-if-not-sent/56920367#56920367).
It failed at max 5/6 times so just set the limit to 7 or so

Comment: The receiving server can return a 4xx result code for any reason it likes - high load because of multiple other incoming connections, disliking your IP address or `EHLO` greeting, or disliking everyone equally. Very often, the problem is not with your code, but with how often it runs or completely dependent on the contents of the message, or even your previous messages or the recipients' reactions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and at least in my case I was able to fix it by setting the `name` property when creating the transport. For your case this would be:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    name: 'example',
    host: 'smtp-relay.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: 'user',
        pass: 'pass'
    }
});
```